Why is an implicitly set relationship property crashing when I'm trying to access it?
I'm using SwiftData with CloudKit and I have the following two classes:
@Model
class Category
{
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Book.category) var books : [Book]?

    var project: Project?

    init()
    {
        self.books = [Book()]
    }
}


@Model
class Book
{
    var createdDate: Date = Date.now
    var category: Category?
    
    var number: String
    {
        if let index = self.category?.books?.sorted(by: { $0.createdDate < $1.createdDate }).firstIndex(of: self)
        {
            return "\(UInt(index + 1))"
        }
        else
        {
            return "??"
        }
    }
    
    init()
    {
    }
}

When I try to create a new Category object, it crashes with EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x2207595d0), pointing to return self.getValue(forKey: \.category) of the Book objects category property. I know that the category property is set implicitly by SwiftData since it's a relationship and I wondered if I was trying to access it too soon, but when I put the code from the computed property number into a function instead, I get the same result. Does anyone know how I can make this code work?
UPDATE: Per questions in the comments below, this is how the Category object gets created:
let project = Project(name: self.userInput, category: Category(name: "Novels"))

And here is the Project class:
@Model
class Project
{
    var name: String = ""
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Category.project) var categories : [Category]?
    var createdDate: Date = Date.now
    var lastSelectedDate: Date = Date.now
    
    init(name: String, category: Category)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.categories = [category]
    }
}


What happens if you first store the result of sorted() (without calling firstIndex) into a local, and then safely dereference that?

@Dai I separated it out like you suggested and it's still dying on the first time where it tries to access category (in my posted example at self.category? and in the separated version at if let category = self.category). Thank you for the suggestion though.

@JoakimDanielson let project = Project(name: self.userInput, category: Category(name: "Novels"))

@JoakimDanielson I added the project class to my original post.

@JoakimDanielson Don't know if it was you, but thanks for closing and referencing the other post, that fixed the problem!
